# SQL Case statement within where

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I write below statement in SQL.

It gives me error at like.

```
select * from a
where
a.Title = case when @Title is null or @Title = '' then a.Title else like %@Title% end
```

Comment: if `@Title` is `null` or empty then this results in `a.Title = a.Title` which makes no sense, actually.

Comment: its a filter criteria, if I pass title null then it should ignore title filter

Comment: @Manish - The a.Title = a.Title conditions returns all records where Title is not null. Is this the expected output?

Comment: Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) would be a good suggested read for you. And `CASE` is an *expression* - it returns a *value*. It's not a statement, and `like %@Title` isn't a value.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done this way:

```
select * from a
where ISNULL(@Title, '') = '' or a.Title like '%' + @Title + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only handle null values but maybe someone can modify it to handle your empty char/varchar values as well...

```
SELECT *
FROM   a
WHERE  a.Title = COALESCE(@Title, a.Title)
```

Comment: I have modfied the question please see

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment about the filter criteria, then this should be what you're after:

```
select * from a
where @Title is null or @Title = '' or a.Title like %@Title%
```

Comment: its like operator %Title%..please see the modified question..i posted a wrong question in hurry..:(

Comment: Then you just need to `OR` the conditions and use a separate `like`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is because you are using %LIKE% which is not a valid construct. To get the desired results, you can run two distinct queries based on the condition instead, like below:

```
if (@Title = null or @Title = '')
select * from a where a.Title = a.Title
else
select * from a where title like @Title
```

Comment: Could you post the complete query please?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix your operators like that (= and like). It looks like you are trying to build a string that says 'like %Title%', but you can't do that. Case will simply return a value to compare to something (a.title).  As several other folks have said, you'll need to use an OR between the two tests.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select 
* 
from @a a
where
a.Title = case when (@Title is null or @Title = '') then a.Title else @Title end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the operator to `LIKE` as there is no difference between `a.title = a.title` and `a.title like a.title` in terms of output

```
select *
from a
where a.Title like case when @Title is null or @Title = '' then a.Title else %@Title% end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Giorgi Nakeuri's answer but for clarifying:
In your query there are some errors:

1. You are using `%@Title%` after `LIKE` that is an invalid expression you need to use a character literal after `LIKE` like `LIKE '%' + @Title + '%'`.
2. You should use a same type result in all your `CASE` branches that is in your statement at first `a.title` then `like %@Title%`.

So your correct query should be something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE 
    1 = CASE
            WHEN @Title IS NULL THEN 1
            WHEN @Title = '' THEN 1
            WHEN a.Title LIKE '%' + @Title + '%' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
```

But you can simplified it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE a.Title LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Title, '') + '%'
```